# External member functions of class template

Tags: c++, class, templates

I have a Binary-Tree class template with several public and private member functions. When the member functions are both defined and implemented inside the class template, it compiles correctly and functions as expected. However, when I move those functions outside of the main class template, I get a *multiplicity* of errors.

- According to this reference, class template functions cannot be made external because the templates are compiled at run-time.  http://www.codeguru.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-333284.html
- However  this MSDN article suggests that "member templates can also be defined outside of a class." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swta9c6e(v=vs.80).aspx

Is there something I am missing here?

```
template <class type>
class BinaryTree{
private:
    Node<type>* root;
    void internalTraverse(Node<type>* n){}
    ......
public:
    ......
};

template <class type>
void BinaryTree<type>::internalTraverse(Node<type>* n){
    if (n == NULL){
        return;
    }
    internalTraverse(n->left);          //  <- This declaration has no storage type or identifier
    cout << "Node: " << n->data << endl;//  Ditto
    internalTraverse(n->right);         //  Ditto
};
......
```

*For full disclosure: This is part of a homework assignment. However, its not directly related to the purpose of the assignment -- more of a tangential problem*

Comment: I think changing the `void internalTraverse(Node<type>* n){}` to `void internalTraverse(Node<type>* n);` would solve the problem. Thats what I get when I see the code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *defined* the member function both inline and out-of-line, so that's multiple. The following compiles:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename> class Node;

template <class type>
class BinaryTree{
private:
  Node<type>* root;
  void internalTraverse(Node<type>* n);  // <--- no definition!
};

template <class type>
void BinaryTree<type>::internalTraverse(Node<type>* n){
  if (n == NULL){
    return;
  }
  internalTraverse(n->left);identifier
  std::cout << "Node: " << n->data << std::endl;
  internalTraverse(n->right);
}
```

Comment: +1 Ah, It's the little things isn't it? Thank you so much. Excellent catch.  Untold hours spend chasing "{}". Clearly the msdn reference was correct.